# Aurelia.js pushState doesn't seem work with nested routes - static resources are lost after refresh

Tags: .htaccess, single-page-application, pushstate, aurelia

My routes:

```
[domain]/manage
[domain]/manage/clients
[domain]/manage/users
```

I've got pushState set to true.

Here's my htaccess:

```
php_value max_input_vars 10000;
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html
AddType text/css .css
```

This worked perfectly in my Angular 1.x app. Moving to Aurelia it works at the `[domain]/manage` level but not at the `[domain]/manage/clients` level. Everything works just fine at all levels until you are two nodes deep into a route and you hit refresh, then suddenly it fails completely.

I've even tried using a node server (spa-server) with exactly the same results. Once you go more than one level deep the static resources can no longer be found. So it can't even bootstrap.

Any thoughts?

Comment: thanks for this, do you happen to have a repo for your example?

Answer (score 1):

The Aurelia Cheat Cheet is telling that u need to: add a base tag to the head of your html document.If you're using JSPM, you will also need to configure it with a baseURL corresponding to your base tag's href.

`<base href="http://www.example.com/page.html">`

`<script>System.config({baseURL: '/manage'});</script>`

also you have to set pushState to true in your router configuration

`config.options.pushState = true;`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure of the following general checks

**1.) Your apache / nginx config is correct**

Nginx - no rewriting required

```
location /api {
    //some proxy backend
}

location / {
   try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

**2.) Make sure your config.js paths are mapped from / (absolute paths)**

```
paths: {
    "*": "/dist/*",
    "github:*": "/jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "/jspm_packages/npm/*"
}
```

**3.) Make sure your index.html uses paths from / (absolute paths)**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/jspm_packages/npm/font-awesome@4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<script src="/jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
<script src="/config.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tjad's answer is only missing one element :

You have to add that if you want pushState to work with aurelia and nested route.

```html
<base href="/">
```

Source: https://github.com/aurelia/documentation/issues/33

Answer (score 0):

When your entry point is a nested route and you are using the pushState configuration with angular router, there seems to be an issue with any subsequent import paths being relative to the current url (was / but is now /manage/).

After much frustration and head scratching, I found this to solve my problem:

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/">
```

(in the head of index.html)

Another successful, if less maintainable solution was to add each route explicity to .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^someroute/?$ "\/index\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^anotherroute/?$ "\/index\.html" [R=301,L]
```